# How can I do so only one checkbox can be selected?

Tags: c#

How can I do so only one box can be selected at the same time?

```
foreach (var i in contestlist)
{
    CheckBox cnb = new CheckBox();
    cnb.Text = i.Name;
    cnb.Location = new Point(10, panel1.Controls.Count * 20);
    panel1.Controls.Add(cnb);
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're using check boxes for that rather than radio buttons? That's precisely what radio buttons are designed for.

Comment: Not really, im just bad i guess. Thanks for the help m8!

Answer (score 3):

If you only want one selected then the case is you want to use radiobuttons instead

If you put radio buttons into a groupbox you can make it so only one can be selected within each groupbox